# PHP replace For a specific occurance

Tags: php, string, str-replace

working on PHP and want to replace the second "space" with a 
 element. To be more precise, if my text is 
`Harry Potter Exists` want to replace the space after `Potter` and display my content as:

> Harry Potter
> Exists

In general i know how to replace every space that exists but having trouble with replacing just the second occurrence of the space.

Thanks for any help!

Substring replace wont be helpful, consider `Harry Potter Really Exists`

> Harry Potter
> Really Exists

So i want to target only and only second space which is after potter, also consider various length in case it's `potttttttttttttttttter` substring will be useless then :)

Comment: You could use a regex for this. `preg_replace` I think would accomplish what you are after. The regex `(.*? .*?) ` Should find everything until the second space and group it into `$1`. Demo, https://regex101.com/r/kX6bQ6/1.

Comment: Also consider `explode`, and piecing back together your string in the form you want, if the regex is unapproachable for some reason.

Comment: I ended up counting the number of blank spaces and adding <Br> instead of the last space at the moment. Since we had to move on will check it back later. Thanks for the preg_replace demo though :)